# Link on body background image

Tags: html, image, background

I am trying to create one advert that use both empty sides of the website content. So i add the advert image as a background on BODY tag. look nice. But the problem is to add a link to it. I start with onclick att on body, but them all site content become clickable. Also i try to use different z-index for body and the content div. Don;t work as well.

This the website i take the idea from. I just want to do some thing similar.
http://www.sport.co.uk/

Any help are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about the body background and use 3 div columns.

Other possibility would be to use [absolute positioning in css](http://www.killersites.com/webDesignersHandbook/absolutePositioning.htm) and for new browsers you can make the div to stay on its position and not to scroll.

Comment: Btw. this would be a good question for http://doctype.com/ (another stackexchange site for designers).